# How to replace all instances of (multiple) whitespace characters (blanks, tabs, newlines) by single blanks in C using array?

Tags: c, algorithm, array-algorithms

I tried using getchar() to solve the problem and it works, but now I am using fgets() to get the text line by line and the whole text is stored in an array. I want to replace all instances of multiple whitespace characters including blanks, tabs, and newline by a single blank. 
This is what I did using getchar():

```
 int c;

while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF
{
    if (c == '\r') continue;
    if (c == '\n') {       
        putchar (c);
        while ((c = getchar ()) == '\n' || c == '\r') {}
        if (c != EOF) ungetc (c, stdin); else break;
        continue;
    }
    if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {  
        putchar (' ');
        while ((c = getchar ()) == ' ' || c == '\t') {}
        if (c != EOF) ungetc(c, stdin); else break;
        continue;
    }
    putchar (c);
}
return 0;
```

}

Now, I am trying to do this:

```
while (1) {
    if (fgets(line,max_len, stdin) == NULL) break;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(line);i++){
        text[n++]=line[i];
    }
}
```

Where each the text is stored in an array from where I want to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

- dont repeat yourself: you need only one getc() and one putc()
- while in the loop, you only need to remember whether the previous outputted character was a blank.
- `break` and `continue` exist for a reason.

---

```
int count;

for(count=0; ; ) {
    int ch; 
    ch = getc(stdin);
    if( ch == EOF) break;
    switch(ch) {
    case ' ':
    case '\t':
    case '\n':
    case '\r':
            if(count++) continue;
            ch = ' ';
            break;
    default:
            count=0;
            break;
            }
    putc(ch, stdout);
    }
```

---

Similar logic for rewriting a character buffer:

---

```
char line[100];
while ( fgets(line,sizeof line, stdin) ) {
    unsigned dst,src,count;  
    for (count=dst=src=0; line[dst]=line[src++];){
        switch(line[dst]) {
        case ' ':
        case '\t':
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
            if(count++) continue;
            line[dst++] = ' ';
            break;
        default:
            dst++;
            count=0;
            break;
            }
        }
    fputs(line,stdout);
    }
```

---

As you can see, you don't need the buffer, it will only complicate things.

Comment: This answer will insert a space into the destination, While the OPs question was: how to condense multiple spaces into a single space

Comment: It will replace multiple whitespace by a single space, and leave all other characters unchanged.